# Intel XDK Launch external not working

Tags: jquery, html, intel, intel-xdk, intel-xdk-contacts

I need to open a link from device native browser.
I Preferred the guided path for launch external link.but it is working in emulator fine but not working in device.
following is my code

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Blank App Designer Project Template</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <style>
                @-ms-viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }                           @viewport { width: 100vw ; zoom: 100% ; }
            @-ms-viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }                                    @viewport { user-zoom: fixed ; }
            /*@-ms-viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }   @viewport { user-zoom: zoom ; min-zoom: 100% ; max-zoom: 200% ; }*/
    </style>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index_main.less.css" class="main-less">

    <script src="intelxdk.js"></script>
        <script src="cordova.js"></script>

    <script src="xhr.js"></script>
        <script src="js/app.js"></script>
        <script src="js/init-app.js"></script>
        <script src="xdk/init-dev.js"></script>
    </head>

<body>
                <div class="upage vertical-col left" id="mainpage">
        <button class="btn widget uib_w_1 d-margins btn-default" data-uib="twitter%20bootstrap/button" data-ver="1" id="openbro" onclick="return Bro();">open browser</button>
    </div>
 <script>
     function Bro(){
           alert("test");
         intel.xdk.device.launchExternal("http://www.google.com");
         //window.location='http://www.google.com';
     }
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: which device/OS is it failing on?  Are you testing using App Preview or the "Debug" tab in the XDK?

Comment: I tested in android kitkat,and also checked after make apk

Comment: I will test this first thing tomorrow in the office

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable plugin Device in project tab in Intel XDK.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the Device plugin is enabled under the IntelXDK tab and try changing

```
    onclick="return Bro();"
```

to:

```
   onclick="Bro();"
```